# How to configure a window setup with a script?

Tags: bash

I would like to know if there is any way to execute an script and get a window setup where several programs are executed and positioned in certain points of the desktop with some desired dimensions. Also, I would like to use virtual desktops. I've searched but I haven't found something similar to build upon, and I don't have a lot of experience with bash so I don't know where to start.

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can script window actions with a number of tools but the one I keep going back to is `xdotool`. It is big and it is complicated so you will want to read some of the examples in `man xdotool`.

If you're running multiple things, I'd consider using `getactivewindow` together with `windowmove` and `windowsize`.

```
# ... run something ...
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0 windowsize --usehints %@ 80 24

# ... run something else ...
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 300 100
```

Alternatively, it might be time to look at a tiling window manager to see if that can manage the launching and placement for you.